# SL4A import fails

Tags: python, sl4a

At the Python terminal, I can run:

```
import random
random.randint(1,6)
```

It gives a number, as expected. However, I save this script as random.py and it fails to run:

```
import random
print random.randint(1,3)
```

It says "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randint'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving your script as something other than random.py.  It's probably importing itself. Delete the old copy of random.py in your CWD before trying again.

Comment: Renaming worked! I forgot about this behavior in Python, thanks.